# convert csv to json as list of dictionary key pairs (python)

Tags: python

Trying to create a python script which converts all csv files in a directory to json format. The json output should be a list of key pair values as below

```
 [{"No.": "1", "Time": "0", "Source": "192.168.252.40", "Destination": "112.156.122.25", "Protocol": "TCP", "Length": "64", "Info": "9145 > 2323 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=12713 Len=0 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT]", "label": "normal"},{"No.": "2", "Time": "0.000615", "Source": "192.168.252.40", "Destination": "115.36.214.222", "Protocol": "TCP", "Length": "64", "Info": "9145 > 23 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=12713 Len=0 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT]", "label": "normal"}]
```

Looked at a few example on here but have only managed to convert a single file and get the json output to be a key value pair on seperate lines as below...

```
{"No.": "No.", "Time": "Time", "Source": "Source", "Destination": "Destination", "Protocol": "Protocol", "Length": "Length", "Info": "Info", "label": "label"}
{"No.": "1", "Time": "0", "Source": "192.168.252.40", "Destination": "112.156.122.25", "Protocol": "TCP", "Length": "64", "Info": "9145 > 2323 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=12713 Len=0 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT]", "label": "normal"}
{"No.": "2", "Time": "0.000615", "Source": "192.168.252.40", "Destination": "115.36.214.222", "Protocol": "TCP", "Length": "64", "Info": "9145 > 23 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=12713 Len=0 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT]", "label": "normal"}
```

The code I have so far is....

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("No.","Time","Source","Destination","Protocol","Length","Info","label")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's gone wrong here. What does your file look like?

Comment: @AdamSmith the output json file is a dictionary for each line of the csv file as shown above. I would like each line of the csv to be an element in a list

Comment: Your input file, I mean.

Comment: its a normal csv file with 8 columns with header and 2 rows on data

Comment: ive tided up the first example of what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to read the whole input in before you write it out, something like:

```
from csv import DictReader
import json

fieldnames = ("No.","Time","Source","Destination","Protocol","Length","Info","label")

with open('file.csv', 'r') as fd:
  data = list(DictRead(fd, fieldnames))

with open('file.json', 'w') as fd:
  json.dump(data, fd)
```

Comment: ah i see ! ok thats perfect works a treat many thanks ! answer accepted and upvoted